# why am I getting this error "cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences (Java.lang.String.int)"

Tags: java, android

hi for the past cuple of months I have been trying to make a game form android studios but at the moment I've been trying to save the highscore and I'm getting this error "cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences (Java.lang.String.int)". I don't understand what to do I have tried other ways but it seems it doesn't work so I tried this way. please help. here is the code.

```js
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

    public static final int WIDTH = 856;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final int MOVESPEED = -5;
    private long smokeStartTime;
    private long missileStartTime;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
    private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
    private ArrayList<TopBorder> topborder;
    private ArrayList<BotBorder> botborder;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int maxBorderHeight;
    private int minBorderHeight;
    private boolean topDown = true;
    private boolean botDown = true;
    private boolean newGameCreated;

    public static int HighScore = 0;

public static SharedPreferences prefs;

private String saveScore = "HighScore";

    //increase to slow down difficulty progression, decrease to speed up difficulty progression
    private int progressDenom = 20;

    private Explosion explosion;
    private long startReset;
    private boolean reset;
    private boolean dissapear;
    private boolean started;
    public static int highScore;



    public GamePanel(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        Context pref;
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKeys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int oldScore = prefs.getInt("highScore", 0);
        int newScore = Player.getScore()*3;
        //update score only if new score is higher
    if(newScore > oldScore ){
       Editor edit = prefs.edit();
       edit.putInt("highScore", newScore);
       edit.commit();
       highScore = newScore;
    }

    String spackage = "com.knight.myfirstgame";

    HighScore = prefs.getInt(saveScore, 0);


        //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        boolean retry = true;
        int counter = 0;
        while(retry && counter<1000)
        {
            counter++;
            try{thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
                thread = null;

            }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

        bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grassbg1));
        player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.helicopter), 65, 25, 3);
        smoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>();
        missiles = new ArrayList<Missile>();
        topborder = new ArrayList<TopBorder>();
        botborder = new ArrayList<BotBorder>();
        smokeStartTime=  System.nanoTime();
        missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        //we can safely start the game loop
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(!player.getPlaying() && newGameCreated && reset)
            {
                player.setPlaying(true);
                player.setUp(true);
            }
            if(player.getPlaying())
            {

                if(!started)started = true;
                reset = false;
                player.setUp(true);
            }
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            player.setUp(false);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void update()

    {
        if(player.getPlaying()) {

            if(botborder.isEmpty())
            {
                player.setPlaying(false);
                return;
            }
            if(topborder.isEmpty())
            {
                player.setPlaying(false);
                return;
            }

            bg.update();
            player.update();

            //calculate the threshold of height the border can have based on the score
            //max and min border heart are updated, and the border switched direction when either max or
            //min is met

            maxBorderHeight = 30+player.getScore()/progressDenom;
            //cap max border height so that borders can only take up a total of 1/2 the screen
            if(maxBorderHeight > HEIGHT/4)maxBorderHeight = HEIGHT/4;
            minBorderHeight = 5+player.getScore()/progressDenom;

            //check bottom border collision
            for(int i = 0; i<botborder.size(); i++)
            {
                if(collision(botborder.get(i), player))
                    player.setPlaying(false);
            }

            //check top border collision
            for(int i = 0; i <topborder.size(); i++)
            {
                if(collision(topborder.get(i),player))
                    player.setPlaying(false);
            }

            //update top border
            this.updateTopBorder();

            //udpate bottom border
            this.updateBottomBorder();

            //add missiles on timer
            long missileElapsed = (System.nanoTime()-missileStartTime)/1000000;
            if(missileElapsed >(2000 - player.getScore()/4)){


                //first missile always goes down the middle
                if(missiles.size()==0)
                {
                    missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.
                            missile),WIDTH + 10, HEIGHT/2, 45, 15, player.getScore(), 13));
                }
                else
                {

                    missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.missile),
                            WIDTH+10, (int)(rand.nextDouble()*(HEIGHT - (maxBorderHeight * 2))+maxBorderHeight),45,15, player.getScore(),13));
                }

                //reset timer
                missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            }
            //loop through every missile and check collision and remove
            for(int i = 0; i<missiles.size();i++)
            {
                //update missile
                missiles.get(i).update();

                if(collision(missiles.get(i),player))
                {
                    missiles.remove(i);
                    player.setPlaying(false);
                    break;
                }
                //remove missile if it is way off the screen
                if(missiles.get(i).getX()<-100)
                {
                    missiles.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //add smoke puffs on timer
            long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - smokeStartTime)/1000000;
            if(elapsed > 120){
                smoke.add(new Smokepuff(player.getX(), player.getY()+10));
                smokeStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<smoke.size();i++)
            {
                smoke.get(i).update();
                if(smoke.get(i).getX()<-10)
                {
                    smoke.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            player.resetDY();
            if(!reset)
            {
                newGameCreated = false;
                startReset = System.nanoTime();
                reset = true;
                dissapear = true;
                explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.explosion),player.getX(),
                        player.getY()-30, 100, 100, 25);
            }

            explosion.update();
            long resetElapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startReset)/1000000;

            if(resetElapsed > 2500 && !newGameCreated)
            {
                newGame();
            }


        }

    }
    public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        if(Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
        final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);

        if(canvas!=null) {
            final int savedState = canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            bg.draw(canvas);
            if(!dissapear) {
                player.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw smokepuffs
            for(Smokepuff sp: smoke)
            {
                sp.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw missiles
            for(Missile m: missiles)
            {
                m.draw(canvas);
            }


            //draw topborder
            for(TopBorder tb: topborder)
            {
                tb.draw(canvas);
            }

            //draw botborder
            for(BotBorder bb: botborder)
            {
                bb.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw explosion
            if(started)
            {
                explosion.draw(canvas);
            }
            drawText(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);

        }
    }

    public void updateTopBorder()
    {
        //every 50 points, insert randomly placed top blocks that break the pattern
        if(player.getScore()%50 ==0)
        {
            topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
            ),topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getX()+20,0,(int)((rand.nextDouble()*(maxBorderHeight
            ))+1)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<topborder.size(); i++)
        {
            topborder.get(i).update();
            if(topborder.get(i).getX()<-20)
            {
                topborder.remove(i);
                //remove element of arraylist, replace it by adding a new one

                //calculate topdown which determines the direction the border is moving (up or down)
                if(topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getHeight()>=maxBorderHeight)
                {
                    topDown = false;
                }
                if(topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getHeight()<=minBorderHeight)
                {
                    topDown = true;
                }
                //new border added will have larger height
                if(topDown)
                {
                    topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.brick),topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getX()+20,
                            0, topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getHeight()+1));
                }
                //new border added wil have smaller height
                else
                {
                    topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.brick),topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getX()+20,
                            0, topborder.get(topborder.size()-1).getHeight()-1));
                }

            }
        }

    }
    public void updateBottomBorder()
    {
        //every 40 points, insert randomly placed bottom blocks that break pattern
        if(player.getScore()%40 == 0)
        {
            botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
                    botborder.get(botborder.size()-1).getX()+20,(int)((rand.nextDouble()
                    *maxBorderHeight)+(HEIGHT-maxBorderHeight))));
        }

        //update bottom border
        for(int i = 0; i<botborder.size(); i++)
        {
            botborder.get(i).update();

            //if border is moving off screen, remove it and add a corresponding new one
            if(botborder.get(i).getX()<-20) {
                botborder.remove(i);


                //determine if border will be moving up or down
                if (botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getY() <= HEIGHT-maxBorderHeight) {
                    botDown = true;
                }
                if (botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getY() >= HEIGHT - minBorderHeight) {
                    botDown = false;
                }

                if (botDown) {
                    botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
                    ), botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1
                    ).getY() + 1));
                } else {
                    botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick
                    ), botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1).getX() + 20, botborder.get(botborder.size() - 1
                    ).getY() - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void newGame()
    {
        dissapear = false;

        botborder.clear();
        topborder.clear();

        missiles.clear();
        smoke.clear();

        minBorderHeight = 5;
        maxBorderHeight = 30;

        player.resetDY();
        player.resetScore();
        player.setY(HEIGHT/2);



        //create initial borders

        //initial top border
        for(int i = 0; i*20<WIDTH+40;i++)
        {
            //first top border create
            if(i==0)
            {
                topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
                ),i*20,0, 10));
            }
            else
            {
                topborder.add(new TopBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick
                ),i*20,0, topborder.get(i-1).getHeight()+1));
            }
        }
        //initial bottom border
        for(int i = 0; i*20<WIDTH+40; i++)
        {
            //first border ever created
            if(i==0)
            {
                botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brick)
                        ,i*20,HEIGHT - minBorderHeight));
            }
            //adding borders until the initial screen is filed
            else
            {
                botborder.add(new BotBorder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick),
                        i * 20, botborder.get(i - 1).getY() - 1));
            }
        }

        newGameCreated = true;


    }
    public void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
        canvas.drawText("DISTANCE: " + (Player.getScore() * 3), 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
        canvas.drawText("HighScore: " + highScore, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);

        if (!player.getPlaying() && newGameCreated && reset) {
            Paint paint1 = new Paint();
            paint1.setTextSize(40);
            paint1.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
            canvas.drawText("PRESS TO START", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2, paint1);

            paint1.setTextSize(20);
            canvas.drawText("PRESS AND HOLD TO GO UP", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2 + 20, paint1);
            canvas.drawText("RELEASE TO GO DOWN", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2 + 40, paint1);
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: JavaScript as NOTHING to do with Java - I removed the tag.

Comment: Java has a lot to do with java though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a global variable as

```
private Context mContext;
```

So when you are on GamePanel you can add this line :

```
this.mContext = context;
```

So at the time you call the `SharedPreferences` you can do it as follows :

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKeys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

### Edit

I can't see where you are using the `Context pref` so I think you forgot to declare it as : `Context pref = context;`

You are creating a `SharedPreferences` object as `public static SharedPreferences prefs;`. Why in your `GamePanel()` put this line `SharedPreferences prefs`? You can use prefs.

### Edit 2

Try if the changes made in your code by me solved your problem.

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

public static final int WIDTH = 856;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int MOVESPEED = -5;
private long smokeStartTime;
private long missileStartTime;
private MainThread thread;
private Background bg;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
private ArrayList<TopBorder> topborder;
private ArrayList<BotBorder> botborder;
private Random rand = new Random();
private int maxBorderHeight;
private int minBorderHeight;
private boolean topDown = true;
private boolean botDown = true;
private boolean newGameCreated;

public static int HighScore = 0;

public static SharedPreferences prefs;

private String saveScore = "HighScore";

//increase to slow down difficulty progression, decrease to speed up difficulty progression
private int progressDenom = 20;

private Explosion explosion;
private long startReset;
private boolean reset;
private boolean dissapear;
private boolean started;
public static int highScore;
private Context mContext; //Add this line <------



public GamePanel(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context; //Add this line <------

    //Context pref;
    //SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKeys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Your SharedPreferences are allready defined
    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKeys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Add this line <---
    int oldScore = prefs.getInt("highScore", 0);
    int newScore = Player.getScore()*3;
    //update score only if new score is higher
if(newScore > oldScore ){
   Editor edit = prefs.edit();
   edit.putInt("highScore", newScore);
   edit.commit();
   highScore = newScore;
}

String spackage = "com.knight.myfirstgame";

HighScore = prefs.getInt(saveScore, 0);


    //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`getSharedPreferences` is a method of `Context`, and subclasses of `Context` such as `Activity`.

`GamePanel` extends `View`, but not `Context`, so there is no such method.

You can just do

```
context.getSharedPreferences(...)
```

If you need to do this outside the constructor, where there is no variable `context` in scope, you can do

```
this.getContext().getSharedPreferences(...)
```

Comment: Why you want him to use this code if on the contructor is passing a Context.......

Comment: @Skizo You're right, the OP could just do `context.getSharedPreferences(...)` but there's no point storing `context` in a field, because you can use `getContext` anyway.

Comment: "but there's no point storing context in a field", it's called Clean code.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to access the pref via an Activity. This is my solution:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class Preferences {
    public SharedPreferences preferences;

    public void setPreferences(Activity activity, String key, String value){
        preferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferencestorage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();

        preferencesEditor.putString(key,value);
        preferencesEditor.apply();
    }

    public String getPreferenceValue(Activity activity, String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferencestorage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getString(key,"");
    }
}
```